# Script works on xampp but not on host server

Tags: javascript, html

The script is supposed to display posts and images from a user. It works well on Xampp but on host server I only see posts but not the images the user has posted. It is blank. On the network tab it cannot be seen either. Here is that script part:

```
var post = function(url){
$('#apost').show();
$('#apost').html('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin afo"></i>'); 
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url, 
    success: function(data){
        var template = $("#itemTemplate").html();
        var result101 = Mustache.render(template, jQuery.parseJSON(data));
        $(".post-content").html(result101);
        $('#apost').hide();
    },
    complete: function(){
        setInterval(post('ajax/post?page='+pagenum), 30000);

    }, 
    error:function(){
        $('.don').html('error loading post');
    }
});        
};
```

Here is the html part:

```
     <div class="media-content">
                <div>{{post}}</div>
                {{#is_photo}}
                <img src="uploads/scaled/{{photo44}}" alt="{{username}}" />
                <p>{{caption}}</p>
                {{/is_photo}}
            </div>
```

Comment: How do you display the images by URL in server-side?

Comment: Upload your images to server.

Comment: There's not enough information in this question

Comment: @nicematt http://mywebsite.com/images/photo.png

Comment: @Antony You uploaded the images in the wrong directory, `"images"`, while in the code you specify `"uploads/scaled/..."`. And relative URLs aren't a good idea, they're dangerous.

Comment: @nicematt I have used  mywebsite.com/images/photo.png as an example to show you the URL my website is using. The image I want to display is inside uploads/scaled. Refer to my edited question please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a path that is accessible from host server. Host server sees your `localhost` path and if the directory tree of your images is not the same as your local server, this is an expected behaviour because there is nothing inside host server's local path.

Two ways:

1. Create exact same path in your host server and put your images there.
2. Apply relative path specifications (don't use `localhost`.../...), instead, get your images from some place like this: `static.yourproject.com/images/xyz.png`

Comment: Use links relative to root, starting with slash: `/images/xyz.png`, that way would work same on any hosting.

Comment: Yes, sure, that's another, and actually more correct approach.

Comment: @skobaljic I have tried <img src="/uploads/scaled/{{photo44}}" alt="{{username}}" /> but it's not working